# Does Lua have something analogous to a header file?

Tags: lua

Suppose I have a global function called `foo()` which I've implemented internally outside of Lua and exposed to the user. Ideally I'd like the user's IDE to be aware of this function for things like autocomplete. The closest thing that comes to mind would be a header file for C/C++, where the function is declared without being defined.

Does Lua have any support for this?

Comment: IDE usually have autocomplete files which can be appended with your own function signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Piglet mentioned there is no out-of-the-box solution for Lua that works across all IDEs. However, I found a typed variant of Lua called [Teal](https://github.com/teal-language/tl) which has support for [declaration files](https://github.com/teal-language/tl/blob/master/docs/declaration_files.md). Teal seems fairly analogous to Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cross IDE mechanism for this in Lua.

There is no way to declare a function prototype in Lua. You can only define function values. So unless you don't provide your functions as Lua code no IDE will be able to parse them for autocompletion. So you would have to provide IDE-specific autocomplete files for your API.

Most Lua development is probably done in a simple text editor anyway.

Provide a good documentation for your API and any Lua developer using it will be happy.